# How can one prove the following inequalities for any integer $k \geq 0$ and $n \geq 1$?

Tags: inequality

1. $\Large{\frac{n^{k}}{\Sigma_{i=1}^{n}i^{k}} \leq \frac{(k+1)}{n}}$
2. $\Large{\frac{n^{k}}{\Sigma_{i=1}^{n-1}i^{k}} \geq \frac{(k+1)}{n}}$

I tried using induction and AM GM inequalities, but they didn't seem to work. I feel like I am missing something obvious here.

Comment: I'm trying to do it using induction but it's tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearrange the inequality to get $$\frac{n^{k+1}}{k+1}\leq \Sigma_{i=1}^n i^k$$
The LHS is the very familiar $$\int_0^n x^kdx$$
Now, is there a way to relate an integral to a sum?

Comment: For the first inequality, I wrote the integral as $\Sigma_{i=1}^{n} \int_{i-1}^{i} x^{k}dx$ and upper bounded each integral by the rectangle it is contained in. The same thing doesn't seem to work for the second inequality.

Comment: Try finding a rectangle that the integral contains for the second inequality.

Comment: Ah ok. I can take the "lower" rectangle. Thanks